# Error 1004 in my Macro while saving a Excel workbook as a CSV for Japanese

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a simple Macro for saving all the Workbooks as separate CSV files.
This works fine on my local machine (English Lang) for paths like **D:\MyFolder** .

But when I am trying the same Macro on another windows machine with Japanese language enabled I am getting 1004 error for `SaveAS` method.

File paths like **D:¥MyFolder¥**

Below is the my code which is causing the error:

> pathSeperator = Application.PathSeparator
>
> strPath = InputBox("Enter EXISTING Directory path like
>   d:\someDirectoryName, d:", , , 1000)
>
> ```
> SaveToDirectory = strPath & pathSeperator & "csv" & pathSeperator
> If Dir(strPath & pathSeperator & "csv", vbDirectory) = "" Then
>
> fso.CreateFolder SaveToDirectory
> Else
>
> fso.DeleteFolder strPath & pathSeperator & "csv"
> fso.CreateFolder SaveToDirectory
>
> End If
>
> For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
>     newName = WS.Name & "-" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "-" & Format(Time, "hhmmss")
>     WS.Copy
>     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs SaveToDirectory & newName, xlCSVMSDOS, Local:=True
>     ActiveWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=False
> Next
> ```

Comment: Can you also include the code where `SaveToDirectory` is declared and set?

Comment: Added the code please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Japanese language machine have you tried changing the font on the visual basic editor to Japanese fonts?

This can be done from the tool->options->format tab.

Edit 22/08/13

A bit of a longshot, but I've read that the Japanese Yen character in ASCII is the same as the / charcter on english language machines, as such using Chr(92) should work in both. On an English language machines it would appear as / whislt on a Japanese machine it would have the yen symbol. A simple test would be to run the following macro on a Japanese machine and see what happens.

```
Sub TestSeperator()

MsgBox Chr(92)

End Sub
```

If this is the case then you need to make changes like the ones below:

```
SaveToDirectory = strPath & Chr(92) & "csv" & Chr(92)
If Dir(strPath & Chr(92) & "csv", vbDirectory) = "" Then

fso.CreateFolder SaveToDirectory
Else

fso.DeleteFolder strPath & chr(92) & "csv"
fso.CreateFolder SaveToDirectory
```

Comment: I will try that , but how does this will help to resolve the issue.Actually The Data is all english just that it will be used by peorsons having japanese languages on their machines.

I suspect the path Seperator '¥' in japanese is causing the error, but i am not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: I was thinking that the VBE may have an issue with the ¥ character if it is not using Japanese fonts

Answer (score 0):

I have tried out your code on my English language machine and managed to raise a 1004 error when I entered the directory path including the final "\"

I have modified the code so that it adds the path seperator if it is not present and the rest of the code assumes it is already in strPath.

```
pathSeperator = Application.PathSeparator

strPath = InputBox("Enter EXISTING Directory path like d:\someDirectoryName, d:", , , 1000)
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

If Right(strPath, 1) <> pathSeperator Then 'added if clause
    strPath = strPath & pathSeperator
End If

SaveToDirectory = strPath & "csv" & pathSeperator  'Removed one pathSeperator
If Dir(strPath & pathSeperator & "csv", vbDirectory) = "" Then

fso.CreateFolder SaveToDirectory
Else

fso.DeleteFolder strPath & "csv" 'Removed one pathSeperator
fso.CreateFolder SaveToDirectory

End If

For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    newName = WS.Name & "-" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "-" & Format(Time, "hhmmss")
    WS.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs SaveToDirectory & newName, xlCSVMSDOS, Local:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=False
Next
```

Comment: Thanks Graham,as mentioned by you the initial code works without mentioning  "/". I am facing issue while saving the files in Japanese path eG  D:¥MyFolder is giving me 1004 in japanese but same D:/MyFolder works in english version.